# CSS flters: задать цвет белому изображению

Tags: css3, css-filters

Есть изображение в виде белого выколотого квадрата, необходимо сделать квадрат цветным (цвет: #3C93F5). Вот такой код не работает:

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
}

img + img {
  filter: saturate(75%) brightness(96%) hue-rotate(211deg);
}
```

```html
<img src=//i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png>
<img src=//i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png>
```

Картинка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png

Comment: Добавь картинку в вопрос и сделай сниппет.

Comment: @Qwerty исходник приведён. Картинка под текстом, просто она маленькая и белая - не видно, выделите статью)

Comment: кто то здесь видит исходник?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, исходник есть, сниппета нет. Я поправил.

Comment: Эм.. А что значит задать цвет? Какой цвет?

Comment: Дайте рисунок-пример того, что вы ожидаете

Comment: @Qwerty, спасибо, неточно задал вопрос, цвет нужен #3C93F5

Comment: @andreymal, что-то у меня возникает подозрение, что кроме серых никакие цвета получить невозможно?

Comment: @Qwertiy хз, у меня в примере из вопроса вторая картинка имеет цвет #F8F5F6

Comment: ...впрочем, от серого это отличается незначительно. Идей пока нет

Comment: @andreymal, где-то не в той точке смотришь. По углам, где есть сглаживание - возможно, но основной цвет `#F5F5F5`.

Comment: @Qwertiy неа, перепроверял раз пять в разных точках ещё со вчера. Скорее всего фаерфокс кривой) / UPD: в хроме таки #F5F5F5

Comment: @andreymal, у белого в hsv получается `(что-угодно, 0, 100)`, значит `hue-rotate` бесполезен. Меняя `v` получаем оттенки серого. А вот как поменять s?

Comment: `filter: saturate(50000000000000000000000000%);` - у меня в хроме получается синий.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать чёрным или серым, можно использовать `invert`:

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

img {
  width: 25%;
}

img + img {
  filter: invert(50%);
}

img + img + img {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src=//i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png>
<img src=//i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png>
<img src=//i.stack.imgur.com/lBHBr.png>
```

Comment: @Qwerty сделать цвет серым довольно просто, а вот цветным...(

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов, что-то есть подозрение, что это невозможно...

Comment: @Qwerty, обидно конечно(

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов, а нет возможности использовать не белый цвет?